# Save an Exchange mailitem to the filesystem local to the Exchange Server using EWS?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

It's my first question/post :-/

**Background to question:-**

I have an ongoing project which is an Azure hosted ASP.NET solution. Its a generic ERP and is intended for small enterprise businesses. An additional requirement came up and I'd like it to be part of the Azure solution (previous attempt to create a VSTO add-in went bad).

**I've been asked to automate this process:-** Users spend a long time (daily basis) manually saving emails into network shared directories according to what company project the emails relate to. E.g. everytime Sally sends or receives an email, she copies and renames the .msg file from outlook into her "G:/" drive (which is just a network share on the enterprise LAN). Someone else in the enterprise has the job of creating a specific directory structure for sally (and her co-workers) to save the emails in (e.g. Correspondance-In, Correspondance-Out etc..). Staff need to be able to search the directories for messages based on some scraped meta data.

I'm considering an exchange web service managed API application in Azure which has a service that polls the Exchange Server (for every user) with a pull subscription to identify new/changed mails. Each identified mail will be then assessed against a rule that the user has pre registered in my application (i.e. from person x with project ID in the subject field). The application will then rename the email and put it in the network share (also scrape metadata to provide search functionality).

**Question:-**

a) How do I get my remote application to request the Exchange Server or CAS to export the MailItem to a local network share using exchange web services in the most efficient way? Preferably without having to deploy something into the enterprise.

b) is this a ridiculous solution?

**Additional Info:**

I expect the typical environment to be quite old. However, I can assume Exchange Server 2007+ and Outlook Clients 2007+ on Win7 (no Office365 though and no sharepoint). I decided to use a pull subscription as it will be a loosely coupled environment and therefore assumed streaming to be not the best fit.

MailItems are likely to contain large attachments (CAD drawings etc) so for obvious reasons, I would like to avoid pulling these across the WAN.

I have investigated the potential to create server side mailbox rules with EWS therefore allowing this exchange server to manage the export - however if I understand correctly, rules don't support exporting MailItems to the filesystem.

Comment: It looks like I will have to deploy some kind of service on premise which I call from Azure to manage the mailItem export...